# cannot access DialogStyle

Tags: android, android-support-library

After updating `android-support` library to `22.2.0` project stopped compiling.

```
error: cannot access DialogStyle
  class file for android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment$DialogStyle not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment$DialogStyle not found
```

Can't find how to work around this issue.

Previously used version was `22.1.1`

Comment: this bug was fixed at support library version 22.2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, it resolved my issue:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile ('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4' }
// and exclude support-v4 from other dependencies as well that might include it
// finally add it, but avoid version 22.2.0...
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1')
```

There is no need to manually add the support-v4 library to your libs directory, the last import ensures that the right version is included in your project.

BTW all of this workaround is not your fault, blame others :)

Comment: Perfect answer! I also do it with 

compile ('com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4' }

Comment: What does `exclude module` do?

Comment: Each dependency can have it own dependencies which in turn can have further dependencies (this is called the library's dependency tree). So when you include a dependency, e.g. `com.android.support:design:22.2.0`, you are practically adding a bunch of libraries, not just a single library. 
With `exclude module`, you tell your build system not to include that specific module. The reason you want to do this is because you already have that library, most probably a different version of it, and you want to control which version to include in your build (though there are other use cases for exclude)

Answer (score 10):

@takoli's answer works in most cases but if you have other dependencies that silently include support-v4 or if you are too lazy to explicitly exclude support-v4 everywhere here is another solution.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0'
// Force stable version of support-v4
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1') {
    force = true
}
```

Update:

AndroidAnnotations released a new version 3.3.2 that resolves this issue. If you are using AndroidAnnotations update to 3.3.2 and use the 22.2.0 support libraries without forcing the old version of support-v4. For more information see [this thread](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1435)

Comment: If I could give this answer more up votes I would. Much more straightforward than the others. (Not that I don't appreciate the previous answers.)

Comment: Why version `22.1.1`?

Comment: 22.1.1 is the last version of support-v4 that doesn't cause the compilation errors. You can use older versions of support-v4 but you are more likely to hit breaking changes on other support lib dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a couple workarounds that worked for us:

## Workaround 1 (some people see a NPE with this, some don't)

I just found a TEMPORARY workaround... till appcompat  fixes this issue:

1. Create the following package in your project src/main/java

android.support.v4.app

2. Create the following new file:

DialogFragment$DialogStyle.java

3. Contents

   package android.support.v4.app;

   // todo remove this file when fixed in appcompat (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175086)

public @interface DialogFragment$DialogStyle {
    }

## Workaround 2 (bit more ugly, but less potential for a build issue)

I found another work-around.... a bit more ugly... but has gotten us around this issue (including the NPE on the above work-around) till appcompat 22.2 is fixed.

1. Create the following package in your project src/main/java

android.support.v4.app

2. Copy the Google v4 FragmentDialog.java code

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java

3. Rename the class (to something like TempFragmentDialog).  You will get a "Duplicate" class error if you don't rename the class.
4. Any FragmentDialog, in your project, that has @Inject will need to extend your copy of the FragmentDialog (example: public class MyFragmentDialog extends TempFragmentDialog)

Comment: I just updated my comments with another workaround that keeps the NPE error from happening (from workaround #1)

Comment: this bug was fixed at support library version 22.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I am using the work around found here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175086#c9

I modified my build.gradle file to say the following in the dependencies section:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

You will also have to exclude it from any other dependencies that use the support library like dagger or facebook.

Then, I added the android-support-v4.jar file found in `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/support/v4` to my libs directory, as that file does seem to have DialogFragment$DialogStyle.

Now, my build is fully working again, but I still hope this can get fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, this is a bug in support library version 22.2.0

Just upgrade to the next update 22.2.1, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case to not to skip an answer: here is also a discussion about this problem https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1435

BTW, do you use Android Annotations in a project where this problem exists ?

Comment: No, we're not using Android Annotations.

Answer (score -2):

It happens if you are using android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.
Try to use android.app.DialogFragment instead.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem when you want to support older Android versions...

Comment: I believe it is a bug in new support library - so this is only temporary solution until the bug is fixed.

Comment: When app is based on `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` there is no easy way to migrate to `android.app.DialogFragment`, so this is no way a solution.

Comment: You cannot use android.app.DialogFragment on android prior v3.2 (api lvl 13).