# Issues with support-v7:22.2.0 on an emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-support-library

The 22.2.0 version of the support libraries [cause compilation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526791/cannot-access-dialogstyle) that can be resolved by forcing the use of an older version of the the support-v4 library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0'
// Force stable version of support-v4
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1') {
    force = true
}
```

This work around fixes the issues on my Android phone but when I run the APK on an emulator I get the following error. Does anyone know how to get this configuration to work on an emulator?

```
Could not find method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow, referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView


/AndroidRuntime(29569): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:792)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:832)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:280)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at com.hightail.android.spaces.activities.NavigationDrawerActivity_.setContentView(NavigationDrawerActivity_.java:72)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at com.hightail.android.spaces.activities.NavigationDrawerActivity_.onCreate(NavigationDrawerActivity_.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(29569):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should use the support-v4 v22.2.0
The appcompat has a dependency, and you can have this type of issue, forcing another version of support-v4.

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti but I can't use support-v4 22.2.0 as it causes  [other problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526791/cannot-access-dialogstyle). This has forced me to use an old version, 22.1.1, which is the last stable release. I realize the true solution is for Google to publish a patch for the 22.2.0 support library but it has been over a month and I'm still waiting. What strange is that the above configuration works on a real device and not on an emulator.

Comment: It crashes on some samsungs too so it's rather critical

Comment: @JacekKwiecień what version of android do you see the crashes. I just found this also crashes on Moto X with 4.4.4.

Comment: For example Note3 with 4.4.1. Had to rollback to 22.1.1

Comment: Me too facing same issu with Android 4.4.4